# How can I view the WMClass attribute of a window in Xorg (linux)?

Tags: linux, xorg, window-manager

I am trying to find a workaround for incorrect grouping of windows in Docky, and I believe the problem lies with the WMClass attribute that is set for each window. However, I do not know how to view this attribute for open windows. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In a terminal, run

```
 xprop WM_CLASS
```

and then click the window in question.

Comment: `WM_CLASS: not found.`

Comment: @Blauhirn run xprop without arguments, you'll get all the properties (and should find WM_CLASS in there, if it's defined)

Comment: WHen i run this command the cursor only works when i click on the desktop. But when i click on the windows it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

it's an old problem, look here:
[bug reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/609168)

Comment: I do not get it

Comment: @Pierre I pasted by mistake something else, I edited my answer